# calculate the internally studentized residual

Tags: statistics, regression, standard-deviation

This is from my textbook:
[image]

it says that ...an ordinary residual divided by an estimate of its standard deviation $s(e_{i})$

As we can see from the example that mean for four residuals is 0, so $s(e_{i})=\sqrt{\frac{(-0.2-0)^2+(0.6-0)^2+(-0.6)^2+(0.2-0)^2}{4-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{0.8}{3}}\neq\sqrt{0.4(1-0.7)}$

where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The studentized residuals are

$$t_i=\frac{\epsilon_i}{\hat\sigma\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$$

Where $\epsilon_i$ is the residual, $h_{ii}$ the leverage and $\hat\sigma$ is the estimate of the standard deviation of residuals, that is

$$\hat\sigma^2=\frac1{n-m}\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i^2$$

Where $n$ is the number of observations (here $4$) and $m$ the number of estimated parameters (here $2$). The sum of square residuals is $0.8$, hence $\hat\sigma^2=\frac12\times0.8$, and

$$t_i=\frac{-0.2}{\sqrt{0.4\times(1-0.7)}}$$

See also [studentized residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual) on Wikipedia and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi) on Cross Validated.

Comment: But the textbook says "Studentized residualsare defined as an ordinary residual divided by an estimate of its standard deviation", is it correct?

Comment: @whoisit Yes, but the estimate of the variance of the residuals is not what you think. It's obtained from the hat matrix. Really, have a look at this Wikipedia article, as it has everything you need.

Comment: @whoisit Also have a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi

Comment: I have read the wikipeida, but it says that "the residuals, unlike the errors, do not all have the same variance the variance decreases as the corresponding x-value gets farther from the average x-value", how come?I think the variance depends on the input data,for example, Height=20+10*age( 0<age<10, I have two same input which are at age 5 their heights are the same, so the variance at age 5 is 0, then I have many different output at age 10, so the variance is obviously greater than 0, how can we say the "variance decreases when x gets farther from the average x-value?